# Need help installing eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am fairly new to this industry so the question I ask might be general.
I am trying to work on a project with jsp and servlets and it requires eclipse ide for ee developers, whenever I try to download one of the packages (e.g luna) and try to open it it crashes saying `unexpected error` what can be the problem?

Do I need to have the normal java ide installed first as well (the non EE developers) version installed as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the [J2EE version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen2). It contains everything for you project.

But you may need a web server (e.g [tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)) separately.

Comment: The issue is that when it asks to connect to tomcat, i need a server, dont i need an  java EE version for that? How do i solve that problem?

Comment: Not sure what version of Eclipse are you using. As I remember, normal version Eclipse IDE does not support JSP or servlet projects. You need an EE version to do so.

Answer (score 0):

just search and download a javaEE from google.Also download a local server i.e, tomcat apache and link it to your eclipse.For servlets you need to download a servlet api jar file which you have to put in libraries of your project. Then you are all set to use it. :)